# Attached Persistent disk not shown

Tags: google-compute-engine

Am trying to view disk space on VM instance to which I have a attached Persistent Disk.
From the Cloud console, the disk is shown as attached.

But Using the command: "df -h"; am not able to see the attached Persistent Disk.
Strangely though, am able to cd to the mounted Persistent Disk.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After a new disk is attached to a running instance, the disk is not mounted automatically. You can find the disk under '/dev/disk/by-id'. Once the disk is attached, you can format and mount the disk using the following command:

```
sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" /dev/disk/by-id/<disk_name> <mount_point>
```

More information can be found here: [Attaching a persistent disk to an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#attach_disk)

Comment: The disk is mounted, else I guess wouldn't have been able to "cd" to the disk (mount point). Also, my application is able to use and store documents on the mount path.

Comment: Executed below commands and it worked : 
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_s4vm1-secondarydisk 

sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_s4vm1-secondarydisk /mnt/d1/

Answer (score 1):

Executed below commands and it worked :

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_s4vm1-www.stutzen.co
```

Above command will format the disk which success message in console. The Disk-ID will be different based on the name provided while creating disk. You can view all attached disk by executing below command

```
 cat /dev/disk/by-id/
```

Then execute below command to mount the disk in required location.

```
sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_s4vm1-www.stutzen.co /mnt/d1/
```

Make sure "/mnt/d1/" directory is already created if not execute

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/d1
```

src: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#formatting

Answer (score 0):

What shows you command:

`sudo fdisk -l`

maybe try `df -ah`

Comment: sorry, i don't notice, that you can cd into it

Comment: sudo fdisk -l; shows the disk details, but does not list it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added additional disk on a running instance, named as "`apps`".

Followed these steps to add disk:

- `sudo mkdir -p /apps`
  List disk id by:
- `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id`
  Found the disk id and used in the following commands.
- `sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_apps`
- `sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_apps /apps`
- `df -h` lists the volume.